# How can I get more than 10 search results on one page?

Tags: 7, search

By default search page shows only 10 results. How can I change it to display unlimited number of results?

Comment: For those interested in back story as to why this is not currently possible to do easily see: http://drupal.org/node/33809

Answer (score 15):

I recommend using views for this. Views comes with a search view included (disabled by default). Use an exposed search term filter to provide the search functionality, and customize other aspects of the view as needed.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. It looks like easiest way, but in Drupal 7, I don't see any search view included.

Comment: You can definitive configure views in a view that it displays the search results like core search.module

Answer (score 5):

Drupal does not currently give you an option to change the number of search results per page. As @beeradb  suggests, you can use the Views module (video tutorial for D7 at http://lin-clark.com/blog/intro-drupal-7-intro-views-pt-1).

There is a feature request for this to go into Drupal 8 http://drupal.org/node/702940.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 7, I have been able to modify the core search result items per page using hook_query_alter in a custom module.  The following code snippet can be used, if you're familiar with using hooks in code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_query_alter
 */
function MY_MODULE_query_alter(&$query) {

  // This is a search result query and we want to change the
  // number of search results per page to 16.
  if ($query instanceof PagerDefault
    && ($tables = $query->getTables())
    && isset($tables['i']['table'])
    && $tables['i']['table'] === 'search_index') {
    $query->limit(16);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find 'search view' in views module. I am using views 7.x-3.7.

To get more than 10 search results on one page in Drupal 7, I have used [search_config](https://drupal.org/project/search_config) module. I used it's latest version '7.x-1.1-beta2'.

Once the module is enabled, you can configure the pager limit from Configuration->Search and metadata->Search settings (admin/config/search/settings) under 'ADDITIONAL NODE SEARCH CONFIGURATION' section. You will see 'Results' section there and you can specify pager limit to show more than 10 search results on one page.

Comment: This does not seem to work with Apache Solr.

Answer (score 0):

The default search view seems to have been removed from the Views module, so here's one I knocked up quickly that you can use as a starting point for your own requirements. Use the Views import dialogue and paste in the code to import it.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'search_test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'search test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'search test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'input_required';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['text_input_required'] = 'Enter some search keywords.';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['text_input_required_format'] = 'filtered_html';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '20';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'No results found.';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Search: Search Terms */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['id'] = 'keys';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['table'] = 'search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['field'] = 'keys';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['operator'] = 'required';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'keys_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['label'] = 'Search Terms';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['operator'] = 'keys_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['identifier'] = 'keys';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'search';
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use search limit module too or use following code in template.php

```
if(arg(0) == "search" && arg(1) == "site") {

$variables['quantity'] = 5; 

}
```